# confused why getting classCastException when junit testing

Tags: java, junit, classcastexception

I am confused as to why I am getting a classCastException.

here is my code:

```
  public RolesResponse findRoleByRoleNameTenant(RolesRequest rolesRequest)
    {
        RolesResponse rolesResponse = new RolesResponse();
        List<Role> roleList = null;
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(rolesRequest.getTenantCode()) && null != rolesRequest.getRoleName())
        {
            roleList = (List<Role>) roleFunctionService.getRolesByRoleNameTenant(rolesRequest.getRoleName().toString(), rolesRequest.getTenantCode());

        }
        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(roleList))
        {

            rolesResponse.setRoles(roleList);
        }
        else
        {

            rolesResponse.setError(LayerContextHolder.getErrorObject());
        }

        return rolesResponse;
    }
```

and here is the test:

```
@Test
    public void findRoleByRoleNameTenantTest()
    {
        RolesRequest rolesRequest = new RolesRequest();

        rolesRequest.setTenantCode("test");
        rolesRequest.setRoleName(RoleName.ADMINATOS);

        RolesResponse rolesResponse = rolesProcessService.findRoleByRoleNameTenant(rolesRequest);
        //Assert.assertNull(rolesResponse.getError()); 
    }
```

and on running the junit test i get classCastException: cannot be cast to java.util.list

and it highlights this line in particular

```
roleList = (List<Role>) roleFunctionService.getRolesByRoleNameTenant(rolesRequest.getRoleName().toString(), rolesRequest.getTenantCode());
```

Comment: What does `roleFunctionService.getRolesByRoleNameTenant()` return?

Comment: @PredragMaric updated in question

Comment: You've updated `findRoleByRoleNameTenant()`, still no code for `getRolesByRoleNameTenant()`.

Comment: there is no code for it? or rather only this @WebMethod
    public Role getRolesByRoleNameTenant(String roleName, String tenant);
}

Comment: classic. comment down question for no reason. i uploaded code on request and explained my problem simply with the hope for some help on the problem. classic stackoverflow douches

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I guess it's because it would probably take you less effort to figure it out yourself then it took you to post the question.

Comment: thanks. different question: how do you mock a list in mockito? i know it's bad practice but needs must

Answer (score 1):

1. You said that `getRolesByRoleNameTenant` returns a `Role`
2. You said that the exception occurs on

   ```
   roleList = (List<Role>) roleFunctionService.getRolesByRoleNameTenant(...));
   ```
3. The class cast exception is telling you that you cannot cast a `Role` to a `List<Role>`.

Basically, either your `findRoleByRoleNameTenant` method is buggy, or the declaration for `getRolesByRoleNameTenant` is incorrect.  Either way, you are attempting to do a class cast that won't and cannot work.

Comment: okay, i didnt write it. just got told to unit test. i'll inform someone, thakns